# Codeigniter Route ID

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I've built a webpage that, in its products page has this prototype for its url

http://www.example.com/products/show/some-really-nice-product/512

The last bit of the url is the product id, which serves the sole purpose of searching the db for the product.

But, is it possible, using routing, to be able to hide that part and still be possible to search the product by its id?

Like 
http://www.example.com/products/show/some-really-nice-product/ ??

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to put a number in your URL, you can't later search by a number/id :)

So you could add a VARCHAR field to the table, say "urlized", and use "some-really-nice-product" as its content for the given ID (you'll need to 'urlize' all your product names and make them unique). Don't forget to index your new field...

Then, you could access the product page using this URL which is very SEO friendly (ends with ".html"):

```
http://www.example.com/products/show/some-really-nice-product.html
```

...by adding a route to CodeIgniter, somehow like this:

```
$route['^products/show/(.*).html'] = 'products/show/$1';
```

In your controller/model, search the database for the string that is passed to "show" method, instead of the ID

Answer (score 1):

if you hide id you can't retrieve that from the url anymore

if you want to hide that anyway just do:

```
$route['products/show/(:any)'] = "products/show/$1/$2";
```